# Cannot Connect ROR Application With MS Sql Server 2008 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have a windows 8 machine in which i have created a ROR application using Rubymine. I want to connect this application with a test database using MS.Sql Server 2008.
What i did in the db was, created a test db and then a simple table to test my app.
Then I install
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter and tiny_tds.
once the installation for completed I made changes to database.yml file to point to right database.

```
development:  
host: "Dell-PC" # used localhost,"localhost" and 127.0.0.1
username: "sa"
password: "****"
database: "music_library"
adapter: "sqlserver"
#pool: 5
#timeout: 5000
```

Now i don't have any model right but when i try to run the following command

```
C:\SecureAlert_SVN\my_app>rake db:migrate
```

Its comes back with the following error.

```
rake aborted!
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'. Make sure
that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other th
an 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to
the Gemfile.
C:/SecureAlert_SVN/my_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter but things are not working out for me.
One thing more I am not using the ODBC way to connect to DB and even don't want to use this way.
I have googled enough about this topic but still no luck.
please tell me what i am missing or i need to install to keep myself moving.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not only install the necessaries gems, you need to add them in your project `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Then run `bundle install` again and even restart your application.

If you go to `localhost:8080` you should get information about the adapter you are using.

Comment: I have rails server 4.0.1. and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.12 so are these two compatiable with each other?

Comment: Then use `3.2.12` in your `Gemfile`. Also, if it is not working again, could you post your `database.yml` file?

Comment: which version of rails i should install and put in the gem file. Please guide.

Comment: rake db:migrate
←[31mBundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 3.2.12) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.2.0) x86-mingw32

    activerecord (4.0.1)

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter - it is said it is working with Rails 3.2

Comment: Please identify the stable version of Rails Server that is compatible with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.12. so that I could install that and try out.

Comment: You can use the 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' with `rails 3.2`. Install `rails 3.2` using and create new application. Then add the `GemFile` the lines above and run bundle install.

Comment: Uninstalling the Rails 4.0.1 gem and its dependencies and reinstalling Rails 3.2.12 worked out for me finally.